# Null space for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If $$T : R^3 →R^3$$ is defined by
>
> $$T(x, y, z) = (2x-z, 3x-2y, x-2y+z) $$
>
> Then,
>
> 1) determine the null space of T
>
> 2) determine whether T is one-to-one
>
> 3) find a basis for the null space of T

For 1), I found a matrix T:
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 0 & -1 \\
 3 & -2 & 0 \\
 1 & -2 & 1     
 \end{pmatrix}

then with reduced echelon row, 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -2/3 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -3/4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0     
 \end{pmatrix}

so $$(x, y, z) = ((1/2)t, (3/4)t, t) $$

This is my solution for find null space of T, but solution (only 1) has tiny solution) said

$$(x, y, z) = (t, (3/2)t, 2t) $$

what's wrong with my answer?

Also, at 3), is basis for null space T is only ((1/2), (3/4), 1) ?

I have no idea with 2).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $((1/2)t,(3/4)t,t)=(T,(3/2)T,2T)$ where $T=(1/2)t$ -- different parametrizations of the same space

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct. Set $t =2u$, and you get the ‘other’ answer. A bsis is whart you found. Personally, again, I would multiply by $2$, to have as few denominators as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution to (1) is the same as the one you quote. It's just a different parametrization. If you replace $t$ by $2s$ they look the same.

(2) Since there is a nontrivial null space the map is not one-to-one. You should be able to write down two vectors that map to the zero vector.

(3) Your answer is correct. It's not the only possible answer.